# returning value 0 when use COUNTIF

Tags: formulas, microsoft-excel

I am stuck in a situation, I am trying to count the number of releases based on each month , but not sure why it keeps returning the value 0?

example :

=COUNTIFS(M2:M5,G19,B2:B5,H18)

M2:M5 : Month column
G19 : September
B2:B5 : Status column
H18 : completed

expectation : returns total number for all completed work for september

Comment: [Welcome to Web Apps Stack Exchange!](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help) It would be best if you could give us a link to a sheet with dummy data.

Comment: Most likely the comparison of "Month" with "September" turns out to be wrong. Attach a test file.